# Anotação @Version

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring

Usando a Anotação @Version, mostra este erro ao tentar fazer o update.

> 18:25:16.650 [http-nio-8080-exec-84] ERROR
>   br.com.netsoft.controller.todos.AtualizacaoMonetariaItemController -
>   Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value
>   mapping was incorrect) :
>   [br.com.netsoft.model.todos.AtualizacaoMonetariaItemEntity#8]

Quando insere está funcionando.

Está mapeado assim

```
    @Version
    @Column(name = "NR_VERSAO", nullable = false)
    public int getNrVersao() {
        return nrVersao;
    }
```

Metodo de alterar

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class BaseRepositorio<T> {

    protected Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public T inserir(T objeto) throws Exception {
        this.entityManager.persist(objeto);
        return objeto;
    }

    public T alterar(T objeto) throws Exception {
        return merge(objeto);
    }

    private T merge(T objeto) {
        this.entityManager.detach(objeto);
        this.entityManager.merge(objeto);
        return objeto;
    }
}
```

Comment: O problema parece ser antes disto. Quem chama este método merge? mas se fosse você eu utilizaria o comportamento original do `merge` (sem usar `detach`).

Answer (score 1):

@guilherme, ajuste o seu método de merge:

```
private T merge(T objeto) {
    this.entityManager.detach(objeto);
    return this.entityManager.merge(objeto);
}
```

O método **entityManager.merge(T entity)** retorna o objeto resultante do merge e com o version incrementado. No seu método **T merge(T objeto)** você está retornando o mesmo objeto que recebeu como parâmetro, portanto, com o valor de version inalterado. Ao tentar salvar uma segunda vez, o version está defazado em relação ao banco e, por isso, a Hibernate dispara a exception de "Row was updated or deleted by another transaction".

O comportamento do método **entityManager.persist(T entity)** já é diferente, pois atualiza o próprio objeto que recebe como parâmetro.

Comment: Obrigado. Imaginei isto. Mas como fazer o correto ? Quebrei a cabeça e não consegui avançar.

Comment: Badaro, não adiantou, mesmo erro.

Comment: @Guilherme, coloque um breakpoint no método alterar para verificar se nrVersao está chegando com o valor correto. Se não estiver. algum ponto da sua rotina está alterando o mesmo ou utilizando uma cópia defazada da entidade.

Comment: Então tenho que verificar o valor antes de alterar. Vou verificar.

Comment: Não funcionou....